# Unable to install chrome on RHEL 7

Tags: google-chrome, rhel7

Receiving an error message while trying to install chrome in RHEL

> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-90.0.4430.212-1.x86_64
> (google-chrome)
> Requires: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit) Unable to install this package libvulkan.so.1()(64bit), unable to find a source to download
> it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for RHEL-7:

```
1. search "vulkan" on https://pkgs.org/search/?q=vulkan
2. download vulkan & vulkan-filesystem for centos-7
3. yum localinstall vulkan*.rpm
4. yum localinstall google-chrome-*.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install vulkan:

```
yum install vulkan
```